# Imported sketchfab model has no shadows in cycles, some do, some don't, seems to do with the shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, lighting, emission

I wonder if anyone can help me with this question.
When I import certain models from sketchfab into blender, some respond to the light in cycles, while others do not cast a shadow. I saw that in the shaders there are some nodes setup in the ones that do not cast the shadow... emission, transparancy... does anyone know how to make these objects interact with world lights? tanks[image]

Comment: hello, in the Object panel > Visibility, there's a Shadow option, is it enabled? Or please share one of these objects without shadow: https://pasteall.org/blend/